# Target an xml node in node js

Tags: node.js, xml, jsdom

I am very new to NodeJS and would request the readers to please be kind if my query is too basic.

I have an xml file that was easy to parse and target certain nodes with DOMParser and querySelector with javascript for the frontend (browser)... but I was trying the same on the backed with node and I realised that DOMParser is not really a part of the backend.. Here's what I am trying..

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data/rogan/gallery.xml`)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((xml) => {
      const xmlDOM = new JSDOM(xml, {
        contentType: "text/xml",
        features: {
          QuerySelector: true,
        },
      });

      const images = xmlDOM.querySelector("img");
      console.log(images);
      res.send(images);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Is the use of querySelector wrong in node? I mean is that a front-end thing and not something we use in node?

I am able to get the XML but I am not sure how to target some specific nodes in the xml that I want to push to an array or an object (I haven't yet reached that stage but first I need to target the nodes)..

Any help/advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you call the `querySelector` in the wrong way. Here is what I found on the documentation of `JSdom`:

```js
dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent
```

In your case, I should be

```js
xmlDOM.window.document.querySelector("img");
```

Comment: thanks @do ..:-).. I tried what you asked me to do and now I get this error .. ReferenceError: dom is not defined .. I would assumed that the xmlDOM should somehow be targetted to get the node that's part of xmlDOM.. I could be wrong.. like I said I am new to nodejs so really don't know how it works

Comment: Ahh, I wrote the wrong variable name. Did you try with `xmlDOM.window.document.querySelector("img");`

Comment: ok.. I think we are making some progress here..;-).. the result when I do xmlDOM.window.document.querySelector("img") is null.. at least it's not an error.. so the format of xmlDOM is some sort of JSDOM object.. is that what it's supposed to be? When I do this xmlDOM.serialize() I get the xml output is string format .. any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe there is no tag that matched the `querySelector`

Comment: I changed the variable that I was targetting from 'img' to 'image' (img was wrong .. hence the null).. and now I get this .. 
Element {
  [Symbol(SameObject caches)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    attributes: NamedNodeMap {},
    childNodes: NodeList {}
  }
}

Comment: so I think you are right and it's working.. am I right?.. now I have this object and  I think my content is in the childNodes.. normally when I am on the frontend I can go do console.log and expand to view the object.. but in node I am completely lost.. what does one do to check the object's content in node?

Comment: I usually use `JSON.stringify` to get the object's content in NodeJS.

Comment: I tried this..  `console.log(JSON.stringify(images.childNodes, null, 4));` and it shows me this.. `{
    "0": {},
    "1": {},
    "2": {},
    "3": {},
    "4": {}
}` ... even though the xml file as 6 nodes of 'image'.. so I am not sure what exactly is the childnodes it's showing me and do you how to view deeper into the nesting?

Comment: I think it will depend on the situation. I had used a library like `JSdom` named `cherio` and met the same problem, I tried to solve it by `console.log` all child nodes. Hope you will find a better solution

Comment: looks like this too many comments are not allowed and I can't move this to chat at I am new to this.. anyways if you do get the time please do check this folder with the xml file and let me know if you could view the 'image' nodes in node.js.. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zmzi7ly0bd1grh2/AACe2k8qO7enICWl87WaCXwIa?dl=0 .. no pressure.. only if possible...